# Why is this R function that returns the frequency of a data frame value not working?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, frequency

I am trying to do a function with two parameters (variable, value). The function returns the frequency of a data frame value. I've written the following code but it returns an error: object "variable" not found. Any ideas of why? Doing it step by step in the console seems to be working but not within the function.

```
data <- data.frame(SEX = c("MASCULINO", "FEMENINO", "FEMENINO","FEMENINO",
                          "MASCULINO", "FEMENINO", "FEMENINO","FEMENINO",
                          "MASCULINO", "FEMENINO", "FEMENINO","FEMENINO",
                          "MASCULINO", "FEMENINO", "FEMENINO","FEMENINO",
                          "MASCULINO", "FEMENINO", "FEMENINO","FEMENINO"),
                   AGE = c(33, 33, 45, 56, 76, 45, 45, 23, 56, 45,
                           19, 23, 45, 56, 28, 36, 53, 49, 47, 22))

value_frequency <- function(variable, value){
        variable <- data$variable
        table <- table(data$variable)
        frequency<- table[[value]]}

value_frequency (SEX, FEMENINO)

Error in frecuencia_valor(SEXO, FEMENINO) : object 'FEMENINO' not found
```

Comment: Without any data we don't know what your function is supposed to be doing exactly and can't test it. Maybe you've gotten confused with the way `dplyr`-type functions make calls with bare column names—this doesn't work in general, so `value_frequency` will be expecting objects to have the names `SEXO` and `FEMENINO`, not for those to be names in a data frame.

Comment: I´ve added the data so it can be tested. As I mentioned, doing it step by step in the console it works. First, I do table(data$SEX) and then table[["FEMENINO"]] and I get 5 as a result. So I can't work out why it doesn't work using the function.

Comment: Because `table[["FEMENINO"]]` and `table[[FEMENINO]]` aren't the same thing. Quotation marks matter. Also, it's a bad & confusing practice to give variables the same name as functions you're using, such as `table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
value_frequency <- function(variable, value){
  variable <- data[,variable]
  table <- table(variable)
  frequency <- table[value]
  return(frequency)
  }

value_frequency ("SEX", "FEMENINO")
FEMENINO 
      15
```

Or a bit shorter, returning only the value, not the associated name:

```
value_frequency <- function(variable, value){
  return(table(data[,variable])[[value]])
  }
```

Comment: Bad practice. You should not write functions that access dataframes outside the function. That applies even if the questioner appears to expect such a bad design. You should instead advise them to use a better design.